# When can we establish an isomorphism between two not-finitely presented groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Assume that finitely generated groups $G$ and $H$, **are not finitely presented**. Fix a generating set $\mathfrak g:=\{g_1,\dotsc,g_n\}$ of $G$. Let $\mathfrak R:=\{R_1,R_2,\dots\}$ be the set of ***all relations*** in $G$. For all non-empty finite subsets $\mathfrak S$ of $\mathfrak R$, there exists a generating set of $H$ whith same size as $\mathfrak g$, which its corresponded set of relations, contain $\mathfrak S$. What we can say about $G$ and $H$. Are they isomorphic? Are they quotient of each other?

Comment: In what set does $\mathfrak R$ live?  Is it another name for $\ker(\operatorname{Free}(\mathfrak g) \to G)$?

Comment: @LSpice: Yes, it is exactly all of $\ker(\text{Free}(\mathfrak g)\rightarrow G)$.

Comment: You may like to look up the Gromov--Grigorchuk space of marked groups.   If I've understood you correctly, your condition means that $G$ is in the closure of the subspace of groups isomorphic to $H$.

Comment: @HJRW as far as I understand, every quotient $H$ of $G$ in which $\mathfrak{g}$ is mapped injectively works...

Comment: @YCor: The question is not about the existence of such groups. I want to know, if it is the case that $G$ and $H$ are always quotient of each other?

Comment: @HJRW: I have two *not-finitely presented* group $G$ and $H$, I can finitely manage the relations, that's mean: For every finite subset $\mathfrak S$ of $\ker(\text{Free}(\mathfrak g)\rightarrow G)$, there is an epimorphism  $\text{Free}(\mathfrak g)\rightarrow H$, which its kernel contains $\mathfrak S$. I want to know, what we can say then about $G$ and $H$?

Comment: "which its kernel contains $S$" is not correct English. Do you mean "whose kernel contains $S$"?

Comment: @YCor: Yes, I mean $\ker(\text{Free}(\mathfrak g)\rightarrow H)$ contains $\mathfrak S$. My apologizes for not following the grammar!

Comment: @YCor, it seems to me that the OP would benefit from an example of a group G which is a limit of groups H, but such that H is not a quotient of G. I'm under the impression that such a (necessarily infinitely presented) G should exist, but don't know a construction. Do you know one?

Comment: @HJRW: at the moment, my first comment yields trivial instances where $G$ is not a quotient of $H$ (e.g., when $H$ is a quotient of $G$ with $H$ finite and $G$ infinite, or $H$ abelian and $G$ non abelian), and this is also in contradiction with your interpretation of the question.

Comment: @YCor, I agree that what you describe is a contradiction to the question as literally read.  But I presume the OP is looking for some non-trivial phenomenon in this vicinity, and so I thought an example of that form might be helpful to him.  It was just a suggestion.

Comment: @HJRW: What extra assumptions needed to make groups $G$ and $H$, at least, quotient of each other? In my problem, these two groups have the same finite class number, also, the described situation is symmetric, means the statement also remains true if we change the role of $G$ and $H$.

Comment: Is it obvious that this situation is really symmetric in $G$ and $H$?

Comment: @LSpice: In my research problem, YES.

Comment: Sorry; I meant:  given the conditions that you state on the ordered pair $(G, H)$, can one deduce the same conditions on the ordered pair $(H, G)$—or is it just that, in your context, usually one happens to know the conditions for both ordered pairs *a priori*?  I don't mean to say that it can't be done, just that I don't see it immediately.